# Any npm packages that allow real-time/cloud variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cloud, real-time

Basically I want to make a competitive 1v1 game using node.js and express. I want to know if there are any npm packages that allow automatic updating of variables, without refresh from a server.

Really stupid example: There is a square on a black canvas and everyone can move it a/o watch others move it.

Another dumb example: A turn based game that prompts you once when your enemy is done, something like: var done = true

A final example: A real-time strategy game like Clash Royale(Though I hate it) or Halo Wars.

Answer (score 0):

Check out socket.io!  You can have all connected sockets affect server-side-variables and therefore have the multiplayer nature you desire.